# Powershell Index math

Tags: powershell, indexing

I have a couple scenarios where a series of arbitrary string values have a specific priority sequence. For example:

```
forgo > log > assert

exception > failure > error > warning > alert
```

And, I need to evaluate an arbitrary number of scenarios that resolve to one of those values and maintain a running status. So, using the simpler example, if every evaluation is `assert` then the final running status would be `assert`. But if a single evaluation is `log` and the rest are `assert`, the the final running status is `log`. And a single `forgo` means the final status is `forgo`, no matter what the mix of individual status results was. I want to provide a human readable running status and individual status, do the math to determine what the new running index is, then return the human readable status.

So, I have this, and it works.

```
$statusIndex = @('assert', 'log', 'forgo')

$runningStatus = 'forgo'
$individualStatus = 'log'

$runningStatusIndex = $statusIndex.indexof($runningStatus)
$individualStatusIndex = $statusIndex.indexof($individualStatus)

if ($individualStatusIndex -gt $runningStatusIndex) {
    $runningStatusIndex = $individualStatusIndex
}

$runningStatus = $statusIndex[$runningStatusIndex]
```

But, this feels like something that happens often enough that there may be a more "native" way to do it. Some built in PowerShell functionality that handles the same thing more elegantly and in less code.

Is my intuition correct, and there is a native way? Or, perhaps a more elegant approach than what I have here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your terms in an array, in precedence order:

```
$statusIndex = @('forgo', 'log', 'assert')
```

Aggregate all your status values and remove any duplicates:

```
$statusValues = 'assert', 'assert', 'log', 'assert' 
$statusValueSet = $statusValues |Sort -Unique
```

Now use the `.Where()` extension method to select only the *first* matching term from the precedence list:

```
$overallStatus = $statusIndex.Where({$_ -in $statusValueSet}, 'First')
```

Value of `$overallStatus` should now be `'log'` as expected.

3-4 lines of code instead of 9-10 :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen That is much more elegant. And allows me to only finalize when I am done. If I need to process 20 conditions I just collect the results and address the final value once. MUCH better.

Comment: Exactly, although you can also keep recursing if you have a large set or a stream of status values - just save the last one, add it to the new values and repeat!

Comment: For the simpler example I just need a final status. But for the larger example it will indeed be a running status and reported in the UI. I love it when one solution lends itself well to multiple uses.